# Drawing lines with PHP on a very tall image and the script just stops drawing. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Tags: php, image, memory

I have a PHP script that creates a very tall image and draws a lot of lines on it (an organizational web kind of look). For the tallest images I've tried creating, the line drawing just stops abruptly toward the middle to bottom of the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDPWh.png

I ran into this problem using imagecreate(), then I found out that imagecreatetruecolor() can handle larger images, so I switched to that. I'm still having the same problem, but the script can now handle somewhat larger images. I think it should be drawing about 1200 lines. The script doesn't take more than 3 seconds to execute. Here's an image that executed completely: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rZpc.png

I adjusted the memory limits with ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M') but my scripts never reach near the limit.

How do I force the script to keep drawing until it finishes? Or how can I use PHP to create an image using less memory (which I think is the problem)?

```
if(sizeof($array[0])<300)
$image=imagecreate($width,$height);
else
$image=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagefill($image,0,0,imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255));
for($p=0; $p<sizeof($linepoints); $p++){
$posx1=77+177*$linepoints[$p][0];
$posy1=-4+46*$linepoints[$p][1];
$posx2=77+177*$linepoints[$p][2];
$posy2=-4+46*$linepoints[$p][3];
$image=draw_trail($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2);
}
imagepng($image,"images/table_backgrounds/table_background".$tsn.".png",9);
imagedestroy($image);

function draw_trail($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2){
$black=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
if($posy1==$posy2)
imageline($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2,$black);
else{
imageline($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx1+89,$posy1,$black);
imageline($image,$posx1+89,$posy1,$posx1+89,$posy2,$black);
imageline($image,$posx1+89,$posy2,$posx2,$posy2,$black);
}
return $image;
}
```

Comment: You could be reaching memory usage per script limits

Comment: can u use js and html5 canvas instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. I figured out, or at least got around, my problem. I was drawing a lot of lines on the image, and the way my code got those points created a lot of repeats, so I still suspect it was a memory problem. I consolidated all the points, taking out the repeats and now it works just fine. Thanks to anyone that tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess that you have created a memory leak, and as you do more operations on a larger image you are eventually hitting PHP's memory limit. Rather than raise the limit, it would be better to find the leak.

Try changing your code so it explicitly deallocates the color you are creating in `draw_trail`. Also, there is no reason to return `$image` since you are passing a resource around.

```
if(sizeof($array[0])&lt;300)
$image=imagecreate($width,$height);
else
$image=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagefill($image,0,0,imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255));
for($p=0; $p&lt;sizeof($linepoints); $p++)
{
    $posx1=77+177*$linepoints[$p][0];
    $posy1=-4+46*$linepoints[$p][1];
    $posx2=77+177*$linepoints[$p][2];
    $posy2=-4+46*$linepoints[$p][3];
    draw_trail($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2);
}
imagepng($image,"images/table_backgrounds/table_background".$tsn.".png",9);
imagedestroy($image);

function draw_trail($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2)
{
    $black=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
    if($posy1==$posy2)
    imageline($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx2,$posy2,$black);
    else
    {
        imageline($image,$posx1,$posy1,$posx1+89,$posy1,$black);
        imageline($image,$posx1+89,$posy1,$posx1+89,$posy2,$black);
        imageline($image,$posx1+89,$posy2,$posx2,$posy2,$black);
    }
    imagecolordeallocate($black);
}
```